# Smooth News Ticker for TV Broadcast - programming options

Tags: actionscript-3

Methods I tried ( target device: desktop):

1. Using Tween or Greensock Tweenlite - simple code but very jerky scroll
2. Using for-loop on the converted movieclip ( ENTER_FRAME or Timer) - bit jerky
3. Using Bitmap.scrollRect     - still more improvement at higher fps
4. Using bitmapData.copyPixels() and cached bitmap    - marked improvement

5 Using Greensock blitmask - more improvement but still not broadcast worthy.

Using timer and `Event.updateAfterEvent()` instead of `ENTER_FRAME` event seems to improve the smoothness. Keeping the fps ( not stage fps) constant and thereby changing the speed of scroll seems to be most effective. Using 'lighter' object like bitmap instead of `MovieClip` or `TextField` seems to do the tick. Is there any other low level method than listed above to get even smoother text scroll? My bet is in using GPU acceleration and double buffering , something like starling libraries, but I am yet to test it.

Comment: Let me guess. It's a mobile app, not a desktop/web application.

Comment: Edited: PC application

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem then unless you scroll some horribly overcomplicated content that take ages to render.

Comment: I am scrolling 1 bitmap or a textfield during the testing, still the animation is not that smooth.

Comment: That is super weird because it shouldn't be like that on desktop. If it were a mobile installation, Starling would be the way, but with PC/desktop that is abundant with CPU processing you shouldn't be experiencing any lag like at all.

Comment: I have tried on a HP Z420 server with 4 GB ram . We have tested on both CS Pro 5.5 as well as Flash Pro CC ( 64 bit). Slight glitches are seen.

Comment: What FPS you set as default value? And did you test it with any FPS-meter to measure the lag?

Comment: I set it to 30fps . Use get timer() to measure time between frames.

Comment: Adobe scout is a diagnostic tool that will show the fps, errors, cpu load, gpu load, etc.